# How to check "Session" from the .html page in `.NET`

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, rest, session

Basically I am trying to check the `Session` value from the `.html page`. SO what far I done that is

**In ASPX**
I am storing the value in `session` and redirect into an `html` page.

```
Session["user_id_no"] = "1234";
Response.Redirect(url);
```

**From HTML** I am calling an `REST GET` method.

```
var check= $.ajax({
    url: "/loginCheck",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (result) {
        return result;
    },
    async:false
});
```

**REST API and Method implementation**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("loginCheck")]
public bool checkLoginStatus()
{
    SessionClass sc = new SessionClass();
    bool user_id_check = sc.check("user_id_no");       
    return user_id_check;
}
```

**Session Class** is implemented as

```
public class SessionClass : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     public bool check(string sessionName)
     {
         if (Session[sessionName] == null)
             return false;
         return true;
     }
}
```

But I am getting exception.

> HResult=-2147467259
>     Message=Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration.

But in my `web.config`

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
```

I have also went through some question

1. [How to access Session variables and set them in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519454/how-to-access-session-variables-and-set-them-in-javascript)
2. [Getting session value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396070/getting-session-value-in-javascript)
3. ['Session' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969563/session-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)
4. [Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true either in a configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334147/session-state-can-only-be-used-when-enablesessionstate-is-set-to-true-either-in)

Comment: @Div from `4th no SO link` in accepted answer says to configure any one  `enableSessionState="true"` or `sessionState mode="InProc" ` and I have done the secondnd one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried this?

```
using System.Web.SessionState;

public class SessionClass :  IRequiresSessionState
{
     public bool check(string sessionName)
     {
         if (HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionName] == null)
             return false;
         return true;
     }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggest and getting this error `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

Comment: Can you debug because there is no code line in the snippet to raise such error message.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgqzQ.png please check this what I have tried. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

you need to `enableSessionState` in your config as exception says

```
 <system.web>
      <pages enableSessionState="true" /> 
 </system.web>
```

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14334927/3635406) for more information